# How to make sure the barbell is positioned correctly relative to chest when bench pressing?

Tags: barbell

After bench pressing seriously for a few months, I notice that one side the shoulders is a lot more developed, and the other side, the chest. Searching up about why should activation occurs more, I find it that it is due to the line of the barbell not being underneath line along nips when viewed from top down.

So, I theorize that the barbell, from top down view is not perfectly horizontal, but rather tilted. What could be some cues to have it be more horizontal?

Comment: Which side is more developed?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the left side ( non dominant side) has more chest development and my dominant side has more arm development

Comment: Do you have any problems, pain etc on one of the shoulders? If yes I'd look into fixing that first, your body might be compensating to avoid pain.